# Web3.py crashes Jupyter kernel

Tags: python, linux, web3py

I am trying to use the `Web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt()` function on a `CentOS` based cluster running Python 3.9.6 in VSCode.

If I use a Jupyter notebook, the kernel simply crashes with this log:

```
10:35:10.411 [info] Started new session 37f16139-2547-4b71-8fbb-57cad5052c25
10:35:10.493 [info] Generated code for 1 = <ipython-input-1-93be7ee0b1af> with 19 lines
10:35:10.576 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 1 @ 1689690910567
10:35:19.531 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: 
10:35:19.531 [info] Dispose Kernel process 19519.
10:35:19.533 [error] Raw kernel process exited code: undefined
10:35:19.536 [error] Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:2:32375)
    at ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:2:51427
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at v._clearKernelState (~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:2:51412)
    at v.dispose (~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:2:44894)
    at ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:24:113024
    at re (~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:2:1587343)
    at Cv.dispose (~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:24:113000)
    at Ev.dispose (~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.6.1101941928/out/extension.node.js:24:120283)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
10:35:19.536 [warn] Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
10:35:19.538 [info] End cell 1 execution @ 1689690919537, started @ 1689690910567, elapsed time = 8.97s
10:35:19.538 [warn] Cancel all remaining cells due to cancellation or failure in execution
10:35:19.886 [info] End cell 1 execution @ undefined, started @ undefined, elapsed time = 0s
```

If I run the code in terminal, I am getting an `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` message without further details.

The package is correctly installed, since I can run other functions (e.g., get the current block number). The code also runs on my Windows 11 machine with `Python 3.8.6`.

Anyone else having this issue? Any known solutions?

Thanks!

P.S. If I connect through `HTTPProvider` rather than `WebsocketProvider`, my Jupyter log also includes this error:

```
  warn(
~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2499: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'cdfbb2b1-fd1e-4336-93dd-0f4c850f5c45' instead of 'b"cdfbb2b1-fd1e-4336-93dd-0f4c850f5c45"'.
  warn(
```